# Oscillation on Angled Rails (Diff Equation)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, mathematical-physics, oscillators, differential-equations

[image]

**This problem was taken from David Morin's *Introduction to Classical Mechanics***

My attempt at solving the problem:

First, I labeled all the relevant forces acting only on one of the particles of mass $m$, which were gravity and the force of the spring acting on said mass.

[image]

The forces contributing to the movement of the object along the rails were:

$$
F_{\text g}=mg\cos(\theta)
\\
F_{\text{spring}}=-k(l-l_i) 
$$
$l$ notates the length of the spring at any given moment while $l_i$ is a constant that represents the initial length of the spring in its equilibrium. $x = 0$ at the point where the two rails meet and $x$ notates the distance along the rail to the particle $m$. Now I shall proceed to solve the differential equation for this motion. First, I would like to invoke the law of sines to relate the length of the spring and the distance $x$. Since the triangle bounded by the spring is isosceles, the two identical angles would measure $\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$

$$
\frac{l}{\sin(2\theta)}=\frac{x}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)}
\\
l=\frac{2x\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}
\\
l=2x\sin(\theta)
$$
Now, we will move onto the differential equation. We must take the force of the spring in the direction of the rail, so we have to multiply it by cosine. $x$ is the current distance along the rail while $x_i$ is a constant that represents the initial distance of the masses from the bottom:
$$
\sum F=m\ddot{x}=-mg\cos\theta - 2k\sin(\theta)(x-x_i)\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)
\\
m\ddot{x} + 2kx\sin^2(\theta) = 2kx_i\sin^2(\theta) - mg\cos(\theta)
$$

Now, I don't know whether I should continue to solve it like an in-homogeneous differential equation because I feel like I'm over-complicating this just to solve for the frequency. Also, the only "variables" here are $\ddot{x}$ and $x$. Everything else are constants, including the trig functions. Any help on how to move forward on this problem or another way of solving this would be high appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Isn't the last equation is the equation for simple harmonic motion?

Comment: @sslucifer, I forgot to add the cosine component of the force of the spring and I edited it now. But, yes, it should be an SMH differential equation. The thing is, I don't know if I am approaching this problem in the right way

Comment: Seems like its the correct approach (well you can also use Lagrangian approach, but I think that will eventually leads up to $F=ma$), use $x(t)=Asin(\omega t)+Bcos(\omega t)$ for further solution.

Comment: Ok, but since the right side of the equation contains a $sin^2\theta$, does your solution $x(t)=Asin(\omega t)+Bcos(\omega t)$ still apply?

Comment: Yeah sure because $\theta$ is just a constant. So it will not affect the solution. Its like $\ddot{x}=-\omega^2 x$ where $\omega^2=2ksin^2(\theta)/m$. Notice that this is only homogeneous solution. You have to add the inhomogeneous part also.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification. I will try that. If you want to write down what you just said as an answer, I could check it and you could get some reputation points or whatever :)
@sslucifer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last equation is just inhomogeneous differential equation for the simple harmonic motion. So use,
$$x(t)=x_{inhm}(t)+Asin(\omega t)+Bcos(\omega t)$$

for further calculations.